# Type-safe Builder: How to combine phantom types

Tags: scala

I am using phantom types in the type-safe builder pattern to ensure methods are called only once as in the following code sample

```
  sealed trait TBoolean
  sealed trait TTrue extends TBoolean
  sealed trait TFalse extends TBoolean

  class Builder[MethodCalled <: TBoolean] private() {

    def foo()(implicit ev: MethodCalled =:= TFalse): Builder[TTrue] = {
      new Builder[TTrue]
    }
  }

  object Builder {
    def apply() = new Builder[TFalse]()
  }
```

I really appreciate this approach since one can use the `.`-operator to chain method calls (unlike with other approaches)
However, this becomes unhandy if there are many methods to guard ending with something like

```
  class Builder[MethodCalled1 <: TBoolean, MethodCalled2 <: TBoolean, ... ,MethodCalledN <: TBoolean]
```

Is there a way to create a "type struct"? Something like the following pseudo code:

```
  type S {
      type MethodCalled1 <: TBoolean
      type MethodCalled2 <: TBoolean
      ...
      type MethodCalledN <: TBoolean
  }

  class Builder[S] private() {

    def foo()(implicit ev: S#MethodCalled1 =:= TFalse): Builder[S#MethodCalled1.TTrue] = {
      new Builder[S#MethodCalled1.TTrue]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand the problem, but have you tried something like `trait S {type MethodCalled1 <: TBoolean; 
... type MethodCalledN <: TBoolean}`, and instead of having a template class `Builder[S]`, you have a class `Builder(s: S)` and refer to inner types like `s.MethodCalled1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were on the right track, you just needed to add a little type refinement:

```
trait BuilderMethods {
  type FooCalled <: TBoolean
  type BarCalled <: TBoolean
}

class Builder[M <: BuilderMethods] private() {
  def foo()(implicit ev: M#FooCalled =:= TFalse): Builder[M {type FooCalled = TTrue}] = {
    new Builder[M {type FooCalled = TTrue}]
  }
  def bar()(implicit ev: M#BarCalled =:= TFalse): Builder[M {type BarCalled = TTrue}] = {
    new Builder[M {type BarCalled = TTrue}]
  }
}

object Builder {
  type UnusedBuilder = BuilderMethods {type FooCalled = TFalse; type BarCalled = TFalse;}
  def apply(): Builder[Builder.UnusedBuilder] = new Builder[UnusedBuilder]()
}

object TestPhantomStruct extends App {
  val newBuilder = Builder()
  val builderFooCalled = newBuilder.foo()
  val builderFooCalledTwice = builderFooCalled.foo() // will not compile
  val builderFooCalledBarCalled = builderFooCalled.bar()
  val builderFooCalledTwiceBarCalled = builderFooCalledBarCalled.foo() // will not compile

  val builderBarCalled = newBuilder.bar()
  val builderBarCalledTwice = builderBarCalled.bar() // will not compile
}
```